# Sytem.Object [] display error within Powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

[image]

I am currently trying to create a powershell script for students to assess their grades. They input their 6 grades at the launch of the script, and are greeted with an option menu. I am able to meet all of my requirements without issue, however for my 3rd section where I need to display corresponding letters to inputted grades, I am getting a "System.Object[]" display when it should be just a grade letter. I am able to get grades to correspond with F, and with D to display, but for any inputs above 60 they show me the system.object display...I am unsure where I am messing up within the syntax. Would greatly appreciate some assistance. I provided a screenshot of display, as well as the scripts code:

```
param (
    [int]$grade1,
    [int]$grade2,
    [int]$grade3,
    [int]$grade4,
    [int]$grade5,
    [int]$grade6
)

# My array of data
[int[]]$grades =($grade1, $grade2, $grade3, $grade4, $grade5, $grade6)

# Menu
do {
Clear-Host
$enteredGrades = "Your Grades: $($grades -join ', ')"
Write-Host "Student Assessment Program:"
Write-Host ""
Write-Host $enteredGrades
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Menu Options:"
Write-Host "  1. Calculate Average"
Write-Host "  2. Credit Count"
Write-Host "  3. Display Letter Grade"
Write-Host "  4. Exit"
Write-Host ""
$choice = Read-Host "Select a Menu Option"

switch ($choice) {
        1 {
           # Calculate Average
           $average = [math]::Round(($grades | Measure-Object -Average).Average, 9)
           $color = if ($average -ge 60) { 'Green' } else { 'Red' }
           Write-Host "Average: $($average -as [string])" -ForegroundColor $color
           Read-Host "Press Enter to continue..."
           }
        2 {
            # Credit Count
            $credits = ($grades | Where-Object { $_ -ge 50 }).Count
            Write-Host "Credits Earned: $credits"
            Read-Host "Press Enter to continue..."
            }
         3 {
             # Display Letter Grade
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $grades.Length; $i++) {
            $classNumber = $i + 1
            $letterGrade = switch -wildcard ($grades[$i]) {
            {$_ -ge 80} { 'A' }
            {$_ -ge 70} { 'B' }
            {$_ -ge 60} { 'C' }
            {$_ -ge 50} { 'D' }
            default { 'F' }
        }
        Write-Host ("Class {0}: {1}" -f $classNumber, $letterGrade)
    }
    Read-Host "Press Enter to continue..."
}
         4 {
            # Exit
            Write-Host "Exiting the program."
             }
        default {
            Write-Host "Invalid choice. Please select 1, 2, 3, or 4."
            Read-Host "Press Enter to continue..."
            }
     }
} while ($choice -ne '4')
```

I have tried an if/else approach to solving the issue, but for some reason I get errors with defining variables and what not. I am certain the syntax was correct, but maybe my logic was flawed somewhere, as I am still a pretty fresh newbie to powershell.

Comment: As an aside: In addition to the primary problem of not short-circuiting the branch evaluations, the `-wildcard` parameter in your [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from how `switch` statements work. Unlike your traditional `if`/`elseif`/`else` statements, the *conditions* continue even after **one** is met. Meaning, if you have a grade of **87**, that checks off all other conditions seeing as they fit: `$_ -ge 50/60/70 and 80`.

This results in an array of objects that PowerShell will display as `System.Object[]` by implicitly calling on [`.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.tostring?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) for each type when placed inside a string returning it's base object type if not otherwise specified through the *formatting*/*type* system.

The work around, or immediate fix, is simply appending a `continue`/`break` (*thanks [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) for poiting out `break` also works*) after each letter to have it skip the rest of the conditions:

```
$letterGrade = switch ($grades[$i]) {
    {$_ -ge 80} { 'A'; continue }
    {$_ -ge 70} { 'B'; continue }
    {$_ -ge 60} { 'C'; continue }
    {$_ -ge 50} { 'D'; continue }
    default { 'F'}
}
```

As to how it's done using *conditional* branching with the `if` statement(s) flow control, here's a quick example where you could substitute it for your current `switch` statement given that you fill the rest of the conditions:

```
$letterGrade = 
    if (($current_grade = $grades[$i]) -ge 80)
    {
        'A'
    }
    elseif ($current_grade -ge 70)
    {
        'B'
    }
    #.... continue with checking $current_grade
    # the else block would be of substitution for the default branch
```

Comment: @NetworkingMania1990, glad to help. Good luck to you in your future endeavors.